# Fluent out_file plugin to create single output file for each day

Tags: fluent

I'm using out_file plugin of fluent (version 0.12.35) to write output to file locally. My fluent config looks like :

```
  <source>
    @type forward
    port 24224
    bind 0.0.0.0
  </source>
  <source>
    @type http
    port 8888
    bind 0.0.0.0
    body_size_limit 32m
    keepalive_timeout 10s
  </source>
  <match **>
    type file
    path /var/log/test/logs
    format json
    time_slice_format %Y%m%d
    time_slice_wait 24h
    compress gzip
    include_tag_key true
    utc 
    buffer_path /var/log/test/logs.*
  </match>
```

This creates multiple gz file for every ~10min.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  256546 May  6 07:03 logs.20170506_0.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  260730 May  6 07:14 logs.20170506_1.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  261155 May  6 07:25 logs.20170506_2.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  258903 May  6 08:56 logs.20170506_10.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  282680 May  6 09:08 logs.20170506_11.log.gz
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  261973 May  6 10:44 logs.20170506_19.log.gz
```

I want to know the way to create a single gzipped file for each day. Even setting `time_slice_wait` to `24h` didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missed a silly thing in configuration: https://docs.fluentd.org/output/file#append

Updated configuration

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<source>
  @type http
  port 8888
  bind 0.0.0.0
  body_size_limit 32m
  keepalive_timeout 10s
</source>

<match **>
  type file
  path /var/log/test/logs
  format json
  time_slice_format %Y%m%d
  time_slice_wait 24h
  compress gzip
  include_tag_key true
  utc 
  buffer_path /var/log/test/logs.*
  append true
</match>
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is continuing to get errors, in the match block, `type` should also be `@type`.